# Send Byte Array form Spring boot to an angular application?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, audioinputstream

I have used a AudioInputStream , i get it from text to speech with MaryTTS . i want to send this audio to the client Angular in this case .How can i do this with http ? I have put the audio to an array of bytes and how can I send it ?

this methode returns an array of bytes .I want to send it to an angular app and play the audio  .Any help please ?

```
public byte[] generateVoice( ) {


    LocalMaryInterface maryInterface = null;
    try {
        maryInterface = new LocalMaryInterface();
    } catch (MaryConfigurationException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not initialize MaryTTS interface: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (maryInterface != null) audio = maryInterface.generateAudio("this is the first audio");

    } catch (SynthesisException e) {
        System.err.println("Synthesis failed: " + e.getMessage());

    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    try {
        buffer = new byte[audio.available()];

        while ((audio.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("the buffer is being filled");
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buffer;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're going to have to make a stream. take a look at: 
[npm stream-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-buffer)

Comment: thank you for ur answer but do u know how can i send the data from the spring boot to the angular 4 app and how to handle the requests

Comment: I do not sorry thought that might point you in the right direction though